# Represent latitude and longitude in 2D cartesian plane

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I've to represent a series of latitude and longitude point in a cartesian plane, in the 0,0 of the cartesian there are my position around me the other point.

Do you know if there are some algorithm to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you give examples of the data you have and explain what you need to get out of it?

Comment: I've to represent some point of interest around me, but I don't want to use a map, the graphical result is similar a radar. Thanks